# Replace Row DataSets from another DataSets In Spark Java API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two datasets as described below

DS1:

| R_REGIONKEY | R_NAME | R_COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AFRICA | lar deposits. bli... |
| 1 | AMERICA | hs use ironic, ev... |

DS2: Custom encryption program extracts R_NAME from DS1, invoke RestAPI to encrypt the data and creates the below dataset.

| R_NAME |
| --- |
| AVR8oDKFFNpuSWR9V.. |
| AVR8oDL+si82n9k5g... |

I want to replace R_NAME in DS1 with R_NAME from DS2 before DS1 is pushed down the pipeline for further processing. Can't use Union as the dataframes are not identical and join is creating duplicates as there is no common identifier between two data frames.

Can somebody guide me with a sample Spark Java solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no common identifier, you cannot do this in spark. The order of the rows is not static .

Comment: you can modify your custom encryption method to accept key:value pair and return key:encrypted_value as output so that you can join it later, there is no other way

Comment: @Sanket9394 thanks for the nudge. Yes, added the common index for both the data frames and then use the join to solve the issue. I will post my learning as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Pradeepyadav yup implemented a slightly different version for the solution. Will post my learning as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the above problem by adding a common identifier across the two datasets using monotonically_increasing_id() method.

```
   Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("header",Boolean.TRUE).
                csv("/opt/REGION_202107282300.csv");
   Dataset<Row> dfWithUniqueId = df.withColumn("IDX", monotonically_increasing_id());
   dfWithUniqueId.show();
```

DS1:
| R_REGIONKEY | R_NAME   | R_COMMENT         | IDX |
| --------    | -------- |   ------          |  -  |
| 0           | AFRICA   |  larbaose         |   0 |
| 1           | AMERICA  |  s use ironic     |   1 |
| 2           | ASIA     |  ges. thinly even |   2 |

DS2: Custom encryption program extracts R_NAME from DS1, invoke RestAPI to encrypt the data along with IDX value from DS1 and creates the below dataset with IDX value from DS1.

| IDX | R_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | AVR8oDKFFNpuSWR9V... |
| 1 | AVR8oDL+si82n9k5g... |
| 2 | AVR8oDK5VjuvWtnPB... |

Implement the join method on IDX column

```
Dataset<Row> DS3 = DS1.join(DS2,DS1.col("IDX).equalTo(DS2.col("IDX)));
```